# Why directive do not see factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, directive

I try to pass some data from controller to directive using factory. In controller I save data to factory object => catch data in directive.
JS:

```
    .factory('data', function() {
            return {
                product: {}
            }                            
     })
     .controller('productController', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', '$q', '$window', '$stateParams', 'data', function($scope, $location, $http, $q, $window, $stateParams, data) {
            // data available               
}]) 
.directive('combobox', ['data', function(data) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            // data undefined ????
        }
    }
}])
```

In directive I can't catch object from factory. Why?

Comment: It should work..could you create plunkr please..

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/9Bv0IAXbwjcLaOhMCu41?p=preview

Comment: check here I made some changes and it working fine http://plnkr.co/edit/iw2VfWSaRCm3uJnUbQEI?p=preview Factory value is getting there in directive

Comment: Some how it work in my project ) I did not understend why in to not work befor.

Comment: You must have missed some of the dependency in DI array, Keep one thing in mind don't alter there sequence when you are using its `instance` inside function..like you gave plunkr which contain `.controller('test', ['data', function($scope, data) {` which is missing with `$scope` in array and I changed it to `.controller('test', ['$scope', 'data', function($scope, data) {`

Comment: Probubly, you right)

Comment: You are correct.. :)